# How to remove large amounts of white space from a python string?

Tags: python

I know there are a few similar questions to mine but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.
I have a string which is:

```
"subject: Exercise Feedback Form
persona_id: bresse
Q1: Yes
Q1 comments: Yes everything was found A1
Q2: No
Q2 comments: No forgot to email me A2
Q3: Yes
Q3 comments: All was good A3
Q4: No
Q4 comments: It was terrible A4
Q5_comments: Get Alex to make it better






























subject: Issue With App
persona_id: bresse
comments: Facebook does not work comments feedback"
```

As you can see there is a large amount of white space in the middle. How would i remove this using python?

Answer (score 4):

you could use regular expressions and configure the expression to replace n or more spaces/newline/tabs/blanks by one single space:

```
import re

s = "hello     \n   world"
print(re.sub("\s{4,}"," ",s))
```

prints:

```
hello world
```

here it will remove all blanks/newlines/tabs/whatever (`\s` in regex) if there are at least 4 of them, and will replace only by one space (to avoid that words that were separated are collated after the replacement, you can replace that by a newline or no character).

Answer (score 1):

Where's `text` is your string:

```
import re
text = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", "", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
s = """subject: Exercise Feedback Form
persona_id: bresse
Q1: Yes
Q1 comments: Yes everything was found A1
Q2: No
Q2 comments: No forgot to email me A2
Q3: Yes
Q3 comments: All was good A3
Q4: No
Q4 comments: It was terrible A4
Q5_comments: Get Alex to make it better






























subject: Issue With App
persona_id: bresse
comments: Facebook does not work comments feedback"""
s = s.replace("\n\n","")
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
print(re.sub('(?<=\n)\s+\n', '', content))
```

Output:

```
"subject: Exercise Feedback Form
persona_id: bresse
Q1: Yes
Q1 comments: Yes everything was found A1
Q2: No
Q2 comments: No forgot to email me A2
Q3: Yes
Q3 comments: All was good A3
Q4: No
Q4 comments: It was terrible A4
Q5_comments: Get Alex to make it better
subject: Issue With App
persona_id: bresse
comments: Facebook does not work comments feedback"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using re :

Removing useless spaces :

```
' '.join(text.split())
```

Removing useless \n :

```
'\n'.join(filter(None, text.split('\n')))
```